# Android RoboBinding firePropertyChange() undefined error

Tags: android, data-binding, viewmodel, model-view, robobinding

I am currently working on Android data binding application.

I am using android "[RoboBinding](http://robobinding.github.io/RoboBinding/getting_started.html)" library for binding Model-View and View-Model.

I have used sample application from [here](https://github.com/RoboBinding/AndroidMVVM) for reference.

This is my `PresentationModel.java` class :

```
@org.robobinding.presentationmodel.PresentationModel
public class PresentationModel implements
    org.robobinding.property.ObservableBean {
private String name;

public String getHello() {
    return name + ": hello Android MVVM(Presentation Model)!";
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void sayHello() {
    firePropertyChange(name);

}

@Override
public void addPropertyChangeListener(String arg0,
        PropertyChangeListener arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void removePropertyChangeListener(String arg0,
        PropertyChangeListener arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

But it displays error as : *The method `firePropertyChange(String)` is undefined for the type PresentationModel PresentationModel.java*

Tried example with following jar files :

1. robobinding-0.8.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
2. robobinding-0.8.4-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies
3. robobinding-0.8.5-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies

Here is the screen shot of error :

[image: Error Trace]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I am able to run the application.

Below is the solution :

https://github.com/RoboBinding/AndroidMVVM/issues/1

Thanks.

Comment: That solution wasn't very helpful–the collaborator said he'd modify the code to not require AspectJ. I have no idea what version that applies to, but I can only assume it's made it to the latest (v0.8.9 atm). Any idea why I might still have this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use AspectJ you should create a PresentationModelChangeSupport property, and call firePropertyChange() method:

```
@org.robobinding.annotation.PresentationModel
public class PresentationModel implements HasPresentationModelChangeSupport {

    protected PresentationModelChangeSupport mChangeSupport;
    private String name;

    public PresentationModel()
    {
        mChangeSupport = new PresentationModelChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getHello() {
        return name + ": hello Android MVVM(Presentation Model)!";
    }

    public void sayHello() {
        mChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("hello");
    }

    @Override
    public PresentationModelChangeSupport getPresentationModelChangeSupport() {
        return mChangeSupport;
    }
}
```